# Remove specific characters from list python

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to Python. I have a list as follows:

```
sorted_x = [('pvg-cu2', 50.349189), ('hkg-pccw', 135.14921), ('syd-ipc', 163.441705), ('sjc-inap', 165.722676)]
```

I am trying to write a regex which will remove everything after the '-' and before the ',', i.e I need the same list to look as below:

```
[('pvg', 50.349189), ('hkg', 135.14921), ('syd', 163.441705), ('sjc', 165.722676)]
```

I have written a regex as follows:

```
for i in range(len(sorted_x)): 

  title_search = re.search('^\(\'(.*)-(.*)\', (.*)\)$', str(sorted_x[i]), re.IGNORECASE)
     if title_search:
         title = title_search.group(1)
         time = title_search.group(3)
```

But this requires me to create two new lists and I don't want to change my original list. 
Can you please suggest a simple way so that I can modify my original list without creating a new list?

Comment: Here's a hint, you don't need to deal with after the comma in the list, your regex only needs to deal with the "title" so to remove -cu2 you just need to deal with that text string.  Head on over to the python doc for lists/tuples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
result = [(a.split('-', 1)[0], b) for a, b in sorted_x]
```

Example:

```
>>> sorted_x = [('pvg-cu2', 50.349189), ('hkg-pccw', 135.14921), ('syd-ipc', 163.441705), ('sjc-inap', 165.722676)]
>>> [(a.split('-', 1)[0], b) for a, b in sorted_x]
[('pvg', 50.349189000000003), ('hkg', 135.14921000000001), ('syd', 163.44170500000001), ('sjc', 165.72267600000001)]
```